# WhatsApp: Group kick and deletion

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I couldn't find any relevant source for this. So I'm hoping to find an answer  to my simple question here.

If I kick someone out of my WhatsApp group (I'm the group admin), will the chat history on the person's mobile device be removed as well?

Answer (score 2):

No it won't be. The person will simply be shown the message "You have been removed from this group"